# How can i get data between certain dates and fill all in a datatable?

Tags: c#, sql

I never really used sql databases before and i'm struggling at getting data between to dates selected by 2 datetimepickers and put it all in a datatable.

```
private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String InitialDateTL =Convert.ToString(dateTimePickerIDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            String FinalDateTL = Convert.ToString(dateTimePickerFDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            //string SelectedCoin = comboBoxSelectCoinTL.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //string InitialTime = txtInitialTime.Text;
            //string FinalTime = txtFinalTime.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(InitialDateTL);
            MessageBox.Show(FinalDateTL);

            SqlCommand SelectSpecificDataTL = new SqlCommand("Select * from cash where Date between @InitialDate and @FinalDate", database.cash);
            database.cash.Open();

            SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InitialDate", InitialDateTL);
            SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalDate", FinalDateTL);


            SqlDataAdapter ffff = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSpecificDataTL.ToString(), database.cash);

            //SqlDataAdapter GetSpecificData = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //GetSpecificData.SelectCommand = SelectSpecificDataTL;
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            ffff.Fill(data);
            TransactionsLogGraph.DataSource = data;
        }
```

That is what i tried so far, I know it's probably all wrong and that's why I need help!

Comment: Are the dates actually dates in the database or strings? I suspect you need to add the sql parameters as `DateTime` values, not the string representation of the dates. You should always avoid working with dates as strings except for display purposes.

Comment: Hi, this is a print of my database.
https://imgur.com/PbmClA3

Comment: In that case, assign `dateTimePickerIDate.Value` to the parameter (same for other) instead of converting to string. Be cautioned that `AddWithValue` has precision and performance issues in certain circumstances so generally it is good to avoid using it and explicitly set the data type of the parameter - though this side-note is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: That fixed the conversion error but now I got these one.
https://imgur.com/YkkhwOK

Comment: You can edit your question to include the error. When asking on SO be sure to include expected behavior, actual behavior and details of errors.

Comment: You are also using `SqlDataAdapter` wrong. Once again, you are `ToString()`ing something that should not be converted to a string. Since you already assigned a connection to the command, just do this: `... = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSpecificDataTL);` to assign the `SelectCommand` property of the adapter.

Comment: Oh that worked, i thought i had to put `... ,database.cash`, thank you very much for your help!